Логика инвентаря
Я создаю инвентарь. Во многих туториалах по инвентарю видела, что при собирании предмета он удаляется, а при выкидывании из инвентаря создается его копия. Я думаю, это не очень производительно, ведь инвентарь используется постоянно, и каждый раз создавать и удалять предмет просто не выгодно. Я думаю использовать такую логику: когда предмет собираю, то деактивируется его префаб. Когда выкидываю из инвентаря, слот инвентаря очищается и этот префаб снова становится активным, но уже с позицией возле игрока. Я думаю, это неплохой способ, ведь потом эти выкинутые префабы можно переиспользовать. Подскажите пожалуйста, производительна ли моя идея или лучше просто удалять и создавать префабы?

Твой вопрос не имеет никакого смысла, поскольку по нормальному, никаких префабов в инвенторях нет, совсем. Единственную роль которую играет юнити, это view, где только меняется картинка и текст.

Начни с самого простого варианта, то есть просто удаляй и создавай предметы на сцене по необходимости. Если будет тормозить, тогда и будешь думать об оптимизации - пулы объектов и вот это всё. Но тормозить скорее всего не будет, если только не выбрасываешь предметы тугой струёй по миллиону штук в секунду.

Хорошо, я сначала попробую первый способ. Спасибо большое!!
